# connect to mysql database from remote server

Tags: mysql

How can I connect to mysql database on Server2 from different server (Server 1). I have given the remote access to Server1 by specifying its domain name using CPanel of Server2. But when I try to run the PHP script from Server1. It does not connect.

Comment: Why not? firewall? username/password incorrect? Should use SSL? ...

Comment: I checked the database name and its username and the password. Everything correct.
Guide me how to use SSL and how to check Firewall.